# How to fill a face with geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've googled around for a while but none of the solutions have worked for me, my situation is this, I have an example mesh like this:

[image]

If I wanted to fill a face inside, like what you would get if you just pressed F with all vertices selected in regular edit mode, how could I get that same result only with geo nodes?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english <3

Comment: Yes!!!! That worked, thank you so much, I knew it probably had to do with converting to curves but couldnt find the right combination, geonodes are awesome, thanks again <3 <3

EDIT: Btw how can I set your answer as the right one so that green check appears? I cant seem to find it

Comment: i posted this as answer, now you can confirm ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert it to curve, then use fill curve, then convert to mesh again.

Make sure that all z are 0 when using fill curve (else it won't work). So you might have to rotate your mesh/curve before and after fill curve.

Comment: It needing to be laid down on z was the prob for me thanks!